# Why iOS templates do not appear in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

So i have an old PowerPc G4 mac which i recently decided to use for development for iPhone. i updated it with 10.5.8 and re-installed xcode 3.1.4. When i open the code to Open a New Project no pre-defined templates appear for iOS like they do in 3.2 versions of Xcode. The only templates that appear are for Mac OSX. i have done development on xcode 3.2 so never had such a problem on my new mac. Do i need to download these templates or what?? what am i possibly doing wrong??

Comment: Just to be sure: did you install the iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS SDK is supplied for Intel Macs only. The only way to use it on a PowerPC machine is to resort to [third-party hacks](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2008/03/powerpc-sdkhack.html) that may or may not work.